# Paginated Scroll Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, scrollview, windows-phone-8.1

im developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app.

I need to make a scroll with fullscreen-images, and i want to horizontal scroll by one page.

This is very common on IOS and Android, ScrollViews just have a property or method that makes it scroll page by page.

I cant find that option here in WinRT.

How can i achieve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control you're looking for is a `FlipView`.

[MSDN: Adding FlipView controls (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780617.aspx)

It is very simple to use and you can also databind the collection of images.

[image]